# Is the word "moving" here a gerund or a present participle?

Tags: parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles, gerunds-vs-participles

Is the word *moving* as used here in these two sentences gerund or a present participle?

1. The five stages of **moving** to a brand new place.
2. One of the most exciting parts of **moving** to a new place.

Comment: What do ***you*** think? And why? Don't go take a nap, now.

Comment: The gerund clause functions as a complement of the preposition. Btw, I think modern linguists don't distinguish between gerund and participle; they call them both *gerund-participle*.

Comment: related: [What is the grammatical construction behind the word “climbing” in the phrase “climbing wall” or the word “running” in the phrase “running” shoes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303828/what-is-the-grammatical-construction-behind-the-word-climbing-in-the-phrase-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nobody was surprised at John being absent (present participle or gerund?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299578/nobody-was-surprised-at-john-being-absent-present-participle-or-gerund)

Comment: also related, and possible duplicate of: [Is it true that if you use a preposition and then a verb, it must end with “ing”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4554/is-it-true-that-if-you-use-a-preposition-and-then-a-verb-it-must-end-with-ing)

Answer (score 2):

Gerund are like nouns, and participles are like adjectives. You can replace *moving* with a noun and keep the structure of the sentence as it is:

> The 5 stages of [a move] to a brand new place
>
> One of the most exciting parts of [a move] to a new place

Only a noun-like phrase can be the object of a preposition, like *of*. It is therefore a gerund in both examples.